# can not connect to bluetooth headset in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset

After steeping in the wrong path for almost two months i found out what my mistake was.
Now i am pacing a new problem which I cannot find the answer to:
Using this function while trying to connect to the headset:

```
   mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(context, mProfileListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);
    final BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mProfileListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
        public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
            if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
                mBluetoothHeadset = (BluetoothHeadset) proxy;
            }
        }
        public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
             if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
                  mBluetoothHeadset = null;
             }
       }
    };
```

I cannot initialize the mBluetoothHeadset object ,for some reason the debugger wont step into the onServiceConnected function..

Any help will be appreciated...realy needs one
shai

More Info:
Inded what haped was that after a android restart Bluetooth nneded to be enabled'solved in code:
This is the function code:
    Log("PM.CheckForHeadSet","In");

```
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Log("PM.CheckForHeadSet","BlueTooth adapter not found");
        return "Error Bluetooth adapter";
    }
    switch (mBluetoothAdapter.getState()){
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF: 
            Log("PM.CheckForHeadSet.getState"," STATE_OFF");
            mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
            break;
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
            Log("PM.CheckForHeadSet.getState","STATE_TURNING_ON");
            break;
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
            Log("PM.CheckForHeadSet.getState","STATE_ON");
            break;
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
            Log("PM.CheckForHeadSet.getState","STATE_TURNING_OFF");
            break;
    }
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
    if (pairedDevices.size() == 1) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) 
            if(device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                Log("PM.CheckForHeadSet Connected to:",device.getName());
            }
    }
    Log("PM.CheckForHeadSet ServiceListener:","In");
    final BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mProfileListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {

        public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
            if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
                mBluetoothHeadset = (BluetoothHeadset) proxy;
                }
            }
        public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
            if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
                mBluetoothHeadset = null;        }
            }};
    if(mBluetoothHeadset == null)
        Log("PM.CheckForHeadSet","mBluetoothHeadset = null");
    else
        Log("PM.CheckForHeadSet","mBluetoothHeadset = " + mBluetoothHeadset.toString());
    if(context == null)
        Log("PM.CheckForHeadSet","context = null");
    else
        Log("PM.CheckForHeadSet","context = " + context.toString());

    if(mProfileListener == null)
        Log("PM.CheckForHeadSet","mProfileListener = null");
    else
        Log("PM.CheckForHeadSet","mProfileListener = " + mProfileListener.toString());

    if(mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(context, mProfileListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) == true)
         Log("PM.CheckForHeadSet.getProfileProxy","true");
    else        
        Log("PM.CheckForHeadSet.getProfileProxy","false"); 
    Log("PM.CheckForHeadSet","Out");
    return "Set Headset";
```

If i place the GetProfileProxy above the  new ProfileListener (as in the docomantaion example|) the mProfileListener var is still null and getProfileProxy return false

And this is the logcat:

```
03-12 10:09:49.906: D/SpySitter(4205): PM.CheckForHeadSet-In
03-12 10:09:50.968: D/dalvikvm(4205): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
03-12 10:09:59.453: D/SpySitter(4205): PM.CheckForHeadSet.getState-STATE_ON
03-12 10:10:02.640: D/SpySitter(4205): PM.CheckForHeadSet Connected to:-Motorola H790
03-12 10:10:04.226: D/SpySitter(4205): PM.CheckForHeadSet ServiceListener:-In
03-12 10:10:13.945: D/SpySitter(4205): PM.CheckForHeadSet-mBluetoothHeadset = null
03-12 10:10:17.984: D/SpySitter(4205): PM.CheckForHeadSet-context = android.app.Application@408472a0
03-12 10:10:21.820: D/SpySitter(4205): PM.CheckForHeadSet-mProfileListener = com.example.HelloForm.Tools$1@40894d00
03-12 10:10:28.796: D/SpySitter(4205): PM.CheckForHeadSet.getProfileProxy-true
03-12 10:10:31.226: D/SpySitter(4205): PM.CheckForHeadSet-Out
```

Comment: What is the return value of mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(...)? It should return true if the call is successful. You can also query the connection state with BluetoothAdapter#getProfileConnectionState(BluetoothProfile.HEADSET).

Comment: getProfileProxy returns false but the wird thing is that the compiler does not recognize ProfileConnectionState .Do u have any clue?I'm trying to run ather tests

Comment: OK,found out that theProfikeConnectionState is avalable only form api 14/My archos is runinig ver 3.0 api 11.Any ideas why the GetProfileProxy returns false?

Answer (score 1):

getProxyProfile returns false in three cases (this is according to the android-15 source, so it might be slightly different in android-11):

- the Context passed in is null
- the BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener passed in is null
- the int passed in is not one of BluetoothProfile.HEADSET, BluetoothProfile.A2DP, BluetoothProfile.INPUT_DEVICE, BluetoothProfile.PAN, or BluetoothProfile.HEALTH

I'd suggest setting a breakpoint on your call to getProxyProfile to figure out which of these cases is causing the `false` return value.

**edit:** Further info

Bluetooth has to be supported and enabled for the interface methods to be called. If Bluetooth is not supported, `getDefaultAdapter()` will return `null`. If you have an adapter, you can check whether Bluetooth is enabled by calling `isEnabled()` on the adapter. That's pretty straightforward, so you may have already done that.

`onServiceConnected` is called by the `android.content.ServiceConnection` member (`mServiceConnection`) in the `BluetoothHeadset` class, which is in turn called by the Android OS  by virtue of a `bindService` call when the `BluetoothHeadset` object is created. If the binding of this service fails, there should be an error in the logcat message log something like:

> ```
>        "Could not bind to Bluetooth Headset Service"
> ```

with a tag of "BluetoothHeadset". If you don't see this error, things are probably working as they should under the hood.

A final note is that Android only supports one connected headset at a time. Make sure that no headset is connected when you are running this code. On a similar note, many devices only support one bluetooth connection at a time. If that applies to your device, you'll want to make sure it is not already connected when you run this code.

That pretty much exhausts what I know and can easily determine about Bluetooth connections. Hope it helps you solve your problem.

Comment: Ok figure that out,what can be the resones that  public void onServiceConnected will not be caled on  BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mProfileListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() like in this example:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html