# android bluetooth headset getprofileproxy returning null

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset

I am trying to connect a bluetooth headset to my android device using the android developer page as a reference. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

My problem is when i trying calling the getProfileProxy(context, mProfileListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) method, I am unsure of what to pass for context? I located this error from the question here:
[can not connect to bluetooth headset in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532233/can-not-connect-to-bluetooth-headset-in-android)

I am extremely new to this so I will apologize in advance if this is a silly question. I have spent a lot of time trying to research this but every example and documentation I find just has a context variable passed in so I am not sure where I am going wrong. My code, which is more or less a copy from the android documentation is:

// Establish connection to the proxy.
    boolean mProfileProxy = mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(context, mProfileListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);
    Log.d(TAGP,"Get Adapter Success: "+mProfileProxy);
    Log.d(TAGP,"Context: "+context);

```
BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mProfileListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
    public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
        if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
            mBluetoothHeadset = (BluetoothHeadset) proxy;
            Log.d(TAGP,"BLuetooth Headset: "+mBluetoothHeadset);
            Log.d(TAGP,"Proxy: "+proxy);
        }
    }
    public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
        if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
            mBluetoothHeadset = null;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **context** can be an **activity** or **service context**. So if the code above is in a class that extends **Activity** or **Service** you can pass **this**.
You can use my answer at [Using the Android RecognizerIntent with a bluetooth headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991158/using-the-android-recognizerintent-with-a-bluetooth-headset/14993590#14993590)