# Android Bluetooth getProxyProfile returns true but listener is never called

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth

I am trying to get a BluetoothHeadset proxy profile in Android.

I'm using the Kotlin code from the [SDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#Profiles)

In my activity I have a field for the bluetoothHeadset and the profile listener to set it:

```
    var bluetoothHeadset: BluetoothHeadset? = null

    private val profileListener = object : BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener {

        override fun onServiceConnected(profile: Int, proxy: BluetoothProfile) {
            Log.d(TAG, "profile is $profile")
            if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
                bluetoothHeadset = proxy as BluetoothHeadset
            }
        }

        override fun onServiceDisconnected(profile: Int) {
            if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
                bluetoothHeadset = null
            }
        }
    }
```

In onCreate I get the bluetooth adapter and call getProxyProfile:

```
        val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "No Bluetooth Adapter.")
        } else {
            // Verify bluetooth is enabled
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {
                val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
            }

            // Establish connection to the proxy.
            bluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(
                this@MainActivity,
                profileListener,
                BluetoothProfile.HEADSET
            )
```

The weird thing is that *bluetoothHeadset* is never set.

The question [can not connect to bluetooth headset in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532233/can-not-connect-to-bluetooth-headset-in-android) covers situations in which getProxyProfile might fail which is indicated by it returning false. I've confirmed that in my case getProxyProfile is returning *true* and not *false*.

I've also confirmed in logcat that onServiceConnected is never called.

Why is it that getProxyProfile is returning true but the listener is never setting bluetoothHeadset?

Comment: Same problem here, please tell me you solved it @ciferkey

Comment: My two cents - check for Bluetooth permissions

Answer (score 0):

try replacing BluetoothProfile.HEADSET to constant value 1

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile#HEADSET

Comment: Why would that work? It always returns 1 anyways